# Grub screen not showing after installing kali?

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux, dual-boot, grub

I dual booted my system having windows 10 with Kali Linux. After installing, I rebooted but the grub bootloader doesn't appear.
Then I went to my UEFI setting booting was in 'UEFI first' mode I changed it to 'legacy first'. Now the grub screen started appearing. Kali worked well, but windows 10 is not booting up. I reverted the changes ( legacy to UEFI ) and now only my windows worked.
I have changed the Legacy boot to UEFI mode and disabled secure boot. Still nothing happened. What should I do? I have searched answer but no other question gave satisfaction.

Comment: Installing kali-linux in Legacy BIOS was unnecessary. Those internet guides mislead people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed your Kali without **UEFI**  mode, and Windows 10 requires **UEFI** to boot. You will have to reinstall Kali with **UEFI** , only then you will be able to dual boot using `grub`.

Just reinstall using the same partitions with an extra EFI partition. But this time boot your USB in UEFI. [Here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/10/19/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-kali-linux-2-on-a-pc-with-uefi-firmware/) is a guide to help you install using EFI.

Comment: so need to uninstall kali first. can suggest a method. i am quite new to it.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: @Ankit With operating systems, "uninstall" is a concept that frequently doesn't exist (except maybe for some version upgrades). But I'd recommend looking first for a way to install a UEFI-capable bootloader without having to reinstall any of the OSes.